# How can I insert a label element before a Google Custom Search input element?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I am using insertBefore() to try to place a "label" element before a Google Custom Search input element to serve as placeholder text, but with my current code I am getting the error: "Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined". Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1');
        el.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter your search term...');
        el.style.background = '';
        el.style.textIndent = '0';
        el.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
            e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
            e.target.style.textIndent = '0';
            }, false );

<!-- create absolutly positioned label as placeholder text for search -->
        var searchParent = el.parentNode;
        var label = document.createElement('label');
        var labelText = document.createTextNode('Enter your search term...');
        label.appendChild(labelText);
        label.className += 'search-label-placeholder';
        console.log(searchParent);
        console.log(label);
        console.log(el);
        document.searchParent.insertBefore(label, el);

<!-- this doesn't work for adding a placeholder -->      
        var searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');
        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                el.focus( function() {
                el.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter your search term...');
                });
            }, false );
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the parent element instead of the document when using insertBefore().

```
searchParent.insertBefore(label, el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
document.searchParent.insertBefore(label, el);
```

with this:

```
document.insertBefore(label, searchParent);
```

Comment: Error: Only one element on document allowed.